# Synatx error in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which is giving me syntax error. i am not getting it. please help to sort it out.

```
SELECT 
    T3.[AcctName],
    SUM(T0.[DebLTotal]/85) AS buget,(Select sum(T3.[Debit]/85) From JDT1 T3 ) as 'CurrentBudget'
FROM 
    OBGT T0
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         CASE WHEN T1.[AcctCode] = '5001' THEN T1.[AcctName] = 'Salaries'
         END as [AcctName],
         [AcctCode]
     FROM 
         OACT AS T1) AS T3 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T3.[AcctCode]
INNER JOIN 
    OBGS T2 ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId]
WHERE
    T2.[Name] = 'Main Budget 2015'
GROUP BY 
    T3.[AcctName], T2.[Name]
```

I am getting `Incorrect syntax near '='` error on this line

```
SELECT CASE WHEN T1.[AcctCode] = '5001' THEN T1.[AcctName] = 'Salaries'
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to update the column in the case expression...

Comment: yes. @jarlh .. i am not getting idea. if T1.[AcctCode] = '5001' then T2.[AcctName] should be 'Salaries'

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** - it can only **return** a single, atomic value - you **cannot** have an assignment in your `THEN` part!

Comment: @marc_s then how can i get required thing?  if T1.[AcctCode] = '5001' then T2.[AcctName] should be 'Salaries'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your assignment in the middle of the `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT 
     CASE WHEN T1.[AcctCode] = '5001' THEN T1.[AcctName] = 'Salaries'
     END as [AcctName],
     [AcctCode]
 FROM 
     OACT AS T1
```

This will never work, since `CASE` is just an **expression** in T-SQL - it can only **return one atomic value**  - it cannot do assigments or control the flow of code.

You need to use it something like this:

```
SELECT 
     [AcctName] = CASE 
                     WHEN [AcctCode] = N'5001' THEN 'Salaries'
                     ELSE 'Other'
                  END,
     [AcctCode]
 FROM 
     OACT AS T1
```

If your `AcctCode` is 5001 - then you use `Salaries` as your `AcctName` (and if it's another value - what do you want to do?)

**Update:** not sure what you mean by *is executing only else part* - check out this demo:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, AcctCode INT)

INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES(1, 5000), (2, 5001), (3, 5000), (4, 5002), (5, 5001), (6, 4999)

SELECT 
     [AcctName] = CASE 
                     WHEN [AcctCode] = 5001 THEN 'Salaries'
                     ELSE 'Other'
                  END,
     [AcctCode]
 FROM @T1
```

The output will **clearly show** that my `CASE` expression works just fine - for values of `5001`, `AcctName` is set to `Salaries`, while for all other values, it returns `Other`.

Comment: Then 'Other'. by using this i am getting now, The conversion of the nvarchar value '100000000000000' overflowed an int column.

Comment: @Kirat: not sure what your `AcctCode`'s datatype is - since it contains "code", I was *assuming* it was a numeric column. If it's not - then put the single quotes around the value `'5001'` again

Comment: Sorry i did not notice before . your code is executing only else part.

Comment: please tell me the answer. i am not able to put another question.

Comment: @Kirat: I don't know what's happening at your computer - it works just fine for me (see my updated response) - there must be something else causing issues for you - sorry, can't say what that is, from here...

Comment: Please check my ans. i explained there

Comment: @Kirat: you need to show us some **sample data** from that table! I seriously don't know what the heck you're doing....... this code of mine **works just fine** - see the demo - does that work for you?? If that works, and your `CASE` doesn't - then there's something wrong with the way you've set up your `CASE`, or with the data you're comparing to .....

Comment: @marc_s congrats on reach 400k :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it maybe because you put ' around a number? Try writing it as `T1.[AcctCode] = 5001`

Comment: its still giving me same error.if i remove those too

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem, the following line was incorrect

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN T1.[AcctCode] = '5001' THEN T1.[AcctName] = 'Salaries'



  SELECT  T3.[AcctName] ,
        SUM(T0.[DebLTotal] / 85) AS buget ,
        ( SELECT    SUM(T3.[Debit] / 85)
          FROM      JDT1 T3
        ) AS 'CurrentBudget'
FROM    OBGT T0
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT CASE WHEN T1.[AcctCode] = '5001' THEN 'Salaries'
                                 ELSE T1.[AcctName]
                            END AS [AcctName] ,
                            [AcctCode]
                     FROM   OACT AS T1
                   ) AS T3 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T3.[AcctCode]
        INNER JOIN OBGS T2 ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId]
WHERE   T2.[Name] = 'Main Budget 2015'
GROUP BY T3.[AcctName] ,
        T2.[Name]
```

Comment: its not solving.. you removed T2.[AcctName] , i need that . if T1.[AcctCode] = '5001' then T2.[AcctName] should be 'Salaries'

Answer (score 0):

I am getting only else part with this query.

```
SELECT  
    T3.[AcctName] ,
    SUM(T0.[DebLTotal] / 85) AS buget ,
    (SELECT SUM(T3.[Debit] / 85)
     FROM JDT1 T3) AS 'CurrentBudget'
 FROM    
     OBGT T0
 INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT 
          AcctName = CASE 
                         WHEN T1.[AcctCode] = '10' THEN 'Fixed Assets'
                         WHEN T1.[AcctCode] = '50' THEN 'Salaries'
                         ELSE 'Other'
                     END,
          [AcctCode]
      FROM   
          OACT AS T1) AS T3 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T3.[AcctCode]
INNER JOIN 
    OBGS T2 ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId]
WHERE   
    T2.[Name] = 'Main Budget 2015'
GROUP BY 
    T3.[AcctName], T2.[Name]
```

Only `ELSE 'Other'` is working. Whatever I put in my `CASE WHEN`, it is returning me one row that is like :

```
AcctName budget
Other     2312836
```

Comment: What **datatype** is the `AcctCode` column, and what sample data do you have in there??

Comment: @marc_s it is nvarchar(20)

Comment: Can you run this query and also output `AcctCode` in your example?? Does that string have any special characters in it, or does it have a leading space or something like that??

Comment: yes @marc_s i can run . there is nothing like that. i dont know what is wrong. i paste here as well. but your one is working fine. i just dont have any idea why it not working

Comment: @marc_s is it possible if the main select statement is effecting.. may be.. is it?